# Unnest a list of rows for selection in update

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, jooq

Let's say I want to re-order some elements in a single-linked list of records...

The approach that came to mind is to build an array of `(previous, current)` id tuples and then unnest that in the `FROM` clause of an `UPDATE` statement.

I.e. something like this:

```kotlin
private fun updateCompositionElementOrdering(elementIdsInExpectedOrder: List<Int>) {
    val PREVIOUS_ELEMENT = DSL.field("previous_element_id", Int::class.javaObjectType)
    val CURRENT_ELEMENT = DSL.field("current_element_id", Int::class.javaObjectType)

    val previousAndCurrent = elementIdsInExpectedOrder.mapIndexed { i, currentElement ->
        val previousElementId = if (i == 0) null else elementIdsInExpectedOrder[i - 1]
        DSL.row(previousElementId, currentElement)
    }

    ctx
        .update(COMPOSITION_ELEMENT)
        .set(COMPOSITION_ELEMENT.PREVIOUS_COMPOSITION_ELEMENT_ID, PREVIOUS_ELEMENT)
        .from(
            DSL.unnest(previousAndCurrent).`as`(DSL.name("p"), PREVIOUS_ELEMENT.unqualifiedName, CURRENT_ELEMENT.unqualifiedName)
        )
        .where(COMPOSITION_ELEMENT.ID.eq(CURRENT_ELEMENT))
        .execute()
}
```

where `private val ctx: DSLContext`, of course.

But this results in:

```
jOOQ; bad SQL grammar [
    update "public"."composition_element"
    set
        "previous_composition_element_id" = previous_element_id,
        "modified_by_id" = ? 
    from
        unnest(cast(? as any[])) as "values" (previous_element_id, current_element_id)
    where "public"."composition_element"."id" = current_element_id
];

nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "any"
```

(this is with `jOOQ 3.17.4` and `Postgres 13.5`)

Answer (score 0):

jOOQ currently doesn't support unnesting arrays of rows. It probably should: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14505

... but this is a hairy thing also in PostgreSQL. For example:

```sql
select *
from unnest(array[row(1, 2), row(3, 4)]) as t (a, b)
```

Produces:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"

You'd need to specify the column type:

```sql
select *
from unnest(array[row(1, 2), row(3, 4)]) as t (a integer, b integer)
```

There's a feature request for this, but it's not too popular, given how esoteric the feature is: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5926

Maybe, better just use [`DSL.values()`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/values/)?

```java
DSL.values(previousAndCurrent)
   .`as`(DSL.name("p"), 
         PREVIOUS_ELEMENT.unqualifiedName, 
         CURRENT_ELEMENT.unqualifiedName)
```